# Creative evolution of the craft of writing

Tags: creative-writing, writers-block, psychology-of-writing

What according to your understanding liberates a writer from the constraints of a restricted imagination and a restrained style arising out of naïve reverence and limited cognizance of the aesthetics, design, style, and composition of celebrated fiction to emerge with his own style?

Comment: This does not ask a clear question.

Comment: Are you asking about finding your voice? If so, just write. Simple. Write with no boundaries, no set intention (or if you do have one, allow it to be bendable) and write for no one but yourself. Write how you think. That should help your own style emerge. Don't get caught up in how it 'should' or 'shouldn't' be.

Comment: Your comment is apt to be welcome for its simplicity and effectiveness. However, my question is, (if you consider it pertaining to voice), regarding the process or the method to  find that voice or how to emanate it through the craft.

Comment: I am thinking of one answer, but I am afraid it may be against the StackExchange rules...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find your unique style?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/5414/how-do-you-find-your-unique-style)

Comment: Burn your thesaurus.

Answer (score 2):

I have three suggestions:

1. Read. Read. Read. Especially read stuff you don't normally read. Get out of your comfort zone. Way out.
2. Think about what you have read, and ask yourself why it either works or doesn't work.
3. Challenge yourself with writing exercises that limit your word count, subject, point of view, or word choices so that you will be disinclined to rely on your usual writing habits.

Comment: Another challenge suggestion: take the same scene, and write it in the style of several different distinctive well-known authors (e.g. Charles Dickens, Stephen King, Dr Seuss, J.K. Rowling, and Alfred Tennyson...)

Answer (score 1):

This question reminds me of a very general piece of advice for all those seaking to expand their mental capacities:

**Seek out that which contradicts your most firmly held beliefs**

One shouldn't adopt new things simply because they are contradictory, simply experience them with an open mind.

Applied to the OP question:

**Read that which you usually disregard

Interact with people you usually neglect

Visit places you usually avoid**

We are, and always shall remain, captives of our own personal experience. We cannot demolish our personal prison walls. All we can hope, is that we may expand them until the feeling of constraint diminishes.